# Extract data out of HTML table cell

Tags: html, vbscript, extract

I want to extract an information from a website (non-public intranet) with VBScript. It is a time which is always in the same field on the website, but each date different and afterwards I want to create with this information a meeting in my outlook (duration always exactly 1 hour) at exactly this time at the current day. I am fine with opening the website with VBScript and putting the meeting, but I have problems to read out the time information of the website field.

Unfortunately I cannot paste the picture of the full structure here, so I paste you the DOM element of the information I am looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<HTML><BODY id="info_body" aLink="#ff0000" link="#0000ff" bgColor="#ebf7ff" text="#000000" vLink="#800080"><TABLE class="topMargin" border="0" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2" width="600" align="center"><TBODY>    <TR class="data">

<TD>
11:42
</TD>

</TR></TBODY></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

Is this helping you? I would need to set the information (in this case "11:42") to a variant and/or to show it in a Msgbox.
And the structure is:

```
html --> body --> iframe (3rd) --> html --> body --> table (1st) --> tbody
--> tr class = "data" --> td (4th)
```

For opening the website I use:

```vb
SET ie1 = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
myUrl1="http://xxxx" 'website
hwnd = ie1.hwnd
ie1.Navigate myUrl1

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
  If hwnd = Wnd.hwnd Then Set ie1 = Wnd
Next
```

For getting the required information I tried:

1. `MsgBox ie.document.body.innerhtml`

   which works and gives me the full html code.
2. `getElementsByTagName`
3. `firstChild`
4. `ie.document.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(0).childNodes(2).childNodes(3)`

I found these code snippets in the internet and apparently they work for other, but I am sorry, I am not able to adapt to my specific requirements and case.

**UPDATE 27.05.2015:**

With this new versions it works most of the times, but unfortunately not always...

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim ie, b, url
Dim hwnd, oshell, wnd
Dim tbl, iframe, td
Dim c, Zeit1, start_punkt
Dim outl, a, myNameSpace, myFolder, myitem, alle_items, myitem_new, olmeeting
Dim ie_exist

URL = "http://xxxx" 'website

SET ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
hwnd = ie.hwnd
ie.Navigate url

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
If hwnd = Wnd.hwnd Then Set ie = Wnd
Next

DO WHILE ie.ReadyState <> 4
LOOP

'get 3rd iframe in page
Set iframe = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").Item(2).contentWindow

'get 1st table in iframe
Set tbl = iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0)

'get 4th cell in table
Set td = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(8)

Msgbox td.innerText
```

When it is not working I get an unkown error message in line:

```vb
If hwnd = wnd.hwnd then set ie = Wnd
```

@Ansgar:
If I remove the `Set oShell = ...` part I get the error message:

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

And if I remove the `Set oShell = ...` part as well as the `DO WHILE ie.ReadyState` loop, I get unkown error in line:

```vb
Set iframe = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").Item(2).contentWindow
```

Any ideas? At least the version above works most of the times (the tried alternatives result each time in an error), but is there any possibility to fix the problem and make it working EACH time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```vb
url = "http://www.example.com/"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate url

While ie.ReadyState <> 4
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

'get 3rd iframe in page
Set iframe = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").Item(2).contentWindow
'get 1st table in iframe
Set tbl = iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0)
'get 4th cell in table
Set td  = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3)

MsgBox td.innerText
```

BTW, this code is pointless, so drop it:

```vb
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
  If hwnd = Wnd.hwnd Then Set ie1 = Wnd
Next
```

You don't need to re-attach to an Internet Explorer instance when you already have a reference to that instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works!
It took me a while, because I always got an "unkown error" in the line [set iframe] or "object required: 'document.getElementsByTagName(...).Item(...)'" in the same line, but now it works, but I had to keep the re-attachment to the Internet Explorer and to loop until ie.ReadyState <> 4...  
Although I do not fully understand why it is necessary, I am happy that it works now...Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately I get randomly an error message. I updated the Question above. @Ansgar: could you please have a look again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Maria You need to wait until IE has reached `ReadyState = 4`, but you don't need to re-attach the IE window. Remove the `For Each` loop and keep the `Do` loop (you may want to add a `WScript.Sleep 100` to the latter, though). See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried with a public website, and there your solution is working properly, but it seems to be something wrong with my intranet site, as I get always error messages if I remove the "for Each" Loop... Then it is better to keep both loops and get only in ~30% error messages ;). By the way, I realized an additional difference: the public website is opening in the background and the internal one always in the foreground... Minor thing, but I do not understand this neather.

Comment: There's nothing else I could tell you without access to your Intranet website. Sorry.